# How to specify applet dependent jars using CLASSPATH environmental variable in java

Tags: java, applet

I have an applet and it is dependant on some test.jar. So , I have added this jar in CLASSPATH environmental variable.
classpath   /dir/test.jar

But this jar is not recognized by the applet and getting ClassNotFound exception for the class inside this test.jar.

But after adding test.jar in archive attribute, everything is working fine.
Why applet is not recognizing classpath?. Is there any way to specify applet dependencies with out archive attribute?.

Answer (score 0):

The dependent JARs of an applet or indeed of any Java application deployed as a JAR file should be specified in the `Class-Path` entry of the Manifest.

If you run any Java application via `java -jar`, any classpath specified on the command line or the CLASSPATH is ignored and only the Manifest `Class-Path` is observed. You don't state how exactly you're running your applet, but presumably the same applies.

Comment: _JPI_VM_OPTIONS environmental variable setting is also working for me.

Comment: _JPI_VM_OPTIONS  path/to/test.jar

Comment: but this environariable is not working when java next generation plugin is enabled in java control panel. But for my application, I need to enable this flag. Help me is there any other way?

Comment: Means..my requirement is to use any environmental variable to specify applet dependencies.

Comment: I've *given* you the *correct* way. You don't need another way.